# Which is the best way to show and amend data via ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wish to use `ItemsControl` in the project. It perfectly works for adding and deleting template items as per below code.

But I wish to use it for data presenting and amendment and have difficulties with it.

As per below code, I can save data to my `List<Technology> MyTechnList`.
But later I wish to show the data from the list and amend / edit it and save to the same list. How to do it correctly?

```
<Grid x:Name="extendedStackGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="TechnItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="stacks">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
Text="Technology:" />
                    <TextBox
x:Name="technologyTbx" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic"
Text="{Binding TechnologyDescr}" />
                    <Button Tag="{Binding TagIndex}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
Content="­˗" Height="35" Width="35" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Click="DeleteTechn_OnClick" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button x:Name="addSkill" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="18" Content="ADD" Height="30" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="addTechn_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public class Technology
{
    public string TagIndex { get; set; }
    public string TechnologyDescr { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Technology> MyTechnList { get; set; }
    public int TagInd { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTechnList = new List<Technology>();
        TagInd = 0;
        //TechnItemsControl.ItemsSource = MyTechnList;
    }

    private void DeleteTechn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button SelectedButton = (Button)sender;
        foreach (var element in MyTechnList)
        {
            if (element.TagIndex == SelectedButton.Tag.ToString())
            { MyTechnList.Remove(element); break; }
        }
        var item = SelectedButton.DataContext;
        TechnItemsControl.Items.Remove(item);
    }

    private void addTechn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Technology item = new Technology();
        item.TagIndex = "Tag" + TagInd.ToString();
        TechnItemsControl.Items.Add(item);
        MyTechnList.Add(item);
        TagInd++;
    }
```

Edited:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Technology> MyTechnList { get; set; }
    public int TagInd { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTechnList = new List<Technology>();
        TagInd = 0;
        addDataToList();
        ShowDataFromList(MyTechnList);
    }

    private void ShowDataFromList(List<Technology> MyTechnList)
    {
        TechnItemsControl.ItemsSource = MyTechnList;
    }

private void addDataToList()
    {
        Technology temp1 = new Technology();
        Technology temp2 = new Technology();
        Technology temp3 = new Technology();
        temp1.TagIndex = "Tag1";
        temp1.TechnologyDescr = "php";
        temp2.TagIndex = "Tag2";
        temp2.TechnologyDescr = "java";
        temp3.TagIndex = "Tag3";
        temp3.TechnologyDescr = "js";
        MyTechnList.Add(temp1); MyTechnList.Add(temp2); MyTechnList.Add(temp3);
    }
```

Comment: Your question unclear and overly broad. It lacks the [mcve] that we'd need to fully understand your scenario, and does not explain what _specific_ difficulty you're having solving the problem, never mind what you've actually tried already and why that didn't help. Please improve the question. In the meantime, keep in mind that `List<T>` doesn't implement collection-changed notifications. In WPF generally you will use `ObservableCollection<T>` to hold data that is intended for binding to `ItemsControl` and other derived controls. So you should probably start there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don’t think that its connected to collection type, although ObservableCollection<T> would work better.
Using the code, its possible to write data to the List. Later I wish to read and amend the data using the same XAML code. By edited code above, its possible to read data from the List. But when I try to click button add or “-”, I got this exception: “Additional Information: The operation is not valid when the ItemsSource is used. Instead, access and modify items using ItemsControl.ItemsSource.”

Comment: The exception you're getting seems pretty clear to me. You need to modify the bound list, not the `Items` collection itself. And will work only if you are using `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Otherwise, you won't see anything on the UI change, even though the list contents have changed. Please also go read [mcve]; you need to put some effort in to make sure the example you're posting is not just complete, but also contains _the bare minimum_ code required to illustrate what you're asking.

Comment: Peter, noted with thanks to use ObservableCollection<T> and provide minimum code.
But what do you mean about list modification, by which way the bound list should be modified pls?

Comment: The code you posted leaves much to be desired from an MVVM perspective. But, the main thing is to just get rid of statements like `TechnItemsControl.Items.Add(item);` and `TechnItemsControl.Items.Remove(item);`. In the `addTechn_Click()` method, you already are adding to the actual list itself so that would suffice, were you using `ObservableCollection<T>`. The UI list would update automatically. Likewise in the `DeleteTechn_OnClick()` method, you've already got code to modify the actual list. So just use the right collection and get rid of the `TechnItemsControl.Items.Remove(item);` statement

Comment: The whole point of MVVM is that you maintain all of your data in a UI-agnostic way. I.e. the view model/model data structures don't know anything about the view. And then the view itself, i.e. the XAML, is written to reference those data structures through bindings, and WPF will then handle all of the UI updates for you as the underlying model data structures change. You shouldn't be writing any code to manipulate the UI itself at all. ...

Comment: ... Naturally, this all requires that the model data structures be "observable" in some way. In WPF, this primarily involves types which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Peter, sorry for delayed reply.. Ok, I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the class and used the ObservableCollection<T> and deleted the methods you suggested and after the code works perfectly!)) Thank you so much for your detailed suggestions! It was simplified example, hope the same mythology will work for actually projects. Thank you!